# How to read ServiceBus Queue message in Azure function using Logic App?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, azure-servicebus-queues

I'm trying to implement a Poc considering the scenario as,

Trigger LogicApp whenever message arrives in ServiceBus Queue. The message will be sent to/read by Azure Function which will be the next action within the LogicApp. After performing some business processes Azure function will return the response back to Logic App. Based on the response from Azure function, LogicApp will trigger few more functions and then they will send the response back to ServiceBus Queue.

I'm able to invoke/trigger LogicApp when a message arrives in ServiceBus queue. Since I'm newbie to Azure and LogicApp, I'm not sure how can I pass message to Azure Function to read and perform business validation within the LogicApp.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

***Firstly, you need connect service bus to Azure Logic App then in next step by clicking on (+) symbol you can type azure function and follow the below process:***

[image]

***Then click on your Function app:***

[image]

***Then Click on the Azure Function you have in your function app:***

[image]

***Then click on request body and then on Service Bus Message:***

[image]

***So, by this way you can handle Azure Function using Azure Logic Apps:***

[image]

***Taken References from:***

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-functions?tabs=consumption
- [Expose APIs from functions using Azure API Management | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-openapi-definition)